# excel spreadsheet to measure monthly inventory demand

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create spreadsheet to measure monthly inventory demand.
Example:
2 orders received every month from Jan 2016 to Apr 2016.
each order requires 5 items to be shipped per month for 3 months.

Jan 2016 - 2 Jan orders received x 5 items = 10 items needed

Feb 2016 - 2 Jan orders received x 5 items + 2 Feb orders received x 5 items = 20 items needed

Mar 2016 - 2 Jan orders received x 5 items + 2 Feb orders received x 5 items + 2 Mar orders received x 5 items = 30 items needed

Apr 2016 - 2 Feb orders received x 5 items + 2 Mar orders received x 5 items + 2 Apr orders received x 5 items = 30 items needed

May 2016 - 2 Mar orders received x 5 items + 2 Apr orders received x 5 items = 20 items needed

I can do this the long way with bunch of formulas and it takes a long time to calculate. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: For something that seems this constant and this repetitive of a task I would recommend using some sort of Database Application that can house all of this information.

Comment: Thank you. I think excel is the only resource I have. I was looking to see if I missed a smarter way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your order duration is always the same, and your data is listed as below :

```
Month   |   Order Count   |  Item Count | Monthly Inventory Demand
=====================================================
Jan     |        2        |        5    |
Feb     |        3        |       11    |
Mar     |        4        |        8    |
...
```

You could fill the last column with :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B[n-2]:B[n],C[n-2]:C[n])
```

for all rows beyond three.  The first two rows would need to have different sum to reflect the absence of a prior three months to reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, order count per month can vary. Order duration (3) will always be the same.

Comment: My answer assumed that the order count would be different for each month, you would simply place that number in the Order Count column for the given month.

I modified the answer to give additional flexibility, in case your Item Count per Order is also changing between months.